# Accessing ejb-name at run time from inside MDB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

Giving this entry from ejb-jar.xml

```
<message-driven id="my_test_mdb ">
        <description>Some description</description>
        <display-name>MyTest</display-name>
        <ejb-name>MyTestEJB</ejb-name>
        <ejb-class>some.path.to.TestMessageBean</ejb-class>
        <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
        <message-driven-destination>
            <destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</destination-type>
        </message-driven-destination>
</message-driven>
```

Is there a way to access at runtime the values defined for my_test_mdb. I am mainly interested in getting the ejb-name value but the same question should be asked for the others like display-name and so.

I am aware about the fact that I could add some environment entries like below but this looks to me like a sort of duplication and error prone.

```
<message-driven>
    ...
    <ejb-name>MyTestEJB</ejb-name>
    ...
    <env-entry>
            <env-entry-name>ejbName</env-entry-name>
            <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
            <env-entry-value>MyTestEJB</env-entry-value>
    </env-entry>
</message-driven>
```

I tried to put a breakpoint and evaluate new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env") then iterate through either list and listBindings but that will only bring me the env-entry section not what I want.

It is very frustrating as at run time I can inspect some elements and clearly able to see what I am after

```
javaNameSpaceImpl:{appName=someModule,_moduleName=someModuleEJB,_componentName=MyTestEJB,_bootstrapAddress=rir:…etc}
```

Any idea about how can this be achieved?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could parse the .xml file. If you replaced the `ejb-jar.xml` with annotations, you could read the annotated values at run-time.

Comment: That would not work because my class some.path.to.TestMessageBean gets deployed multiple times (about 50 times) as a different MDB. It is just the queue that that MDB is listening to the thing that changes and not the executed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way to retrieve the component name.  I agree that it's unfortunate that there's no java:comp/CompName (ala java:app/AppName and java:module/ModuleName) or EJBContext.getName().  My recommendation in the past has always been the env-entry approach, which I agree is not ideal.

Comment: What about some vendor specific way? Not nice but better than nothing. We are deploying to webshere application server 8.5.

Comment: I'm not aware of any supported APIs for accessing the component name.